# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:56678/session timed out after 60 seconds

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer

```
        string binPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"\Driver";
        System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", binPath);

        //var service = InternetExplorerDriverService.CreateDefaultService();

        InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions()
        {
            AttachToEdgeChrome = true,
            IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true,
            IgnoreZoomLevel = true,
            EnsureCleanSession = true,
            EnableNativeEvents = true,
            InitialBrowserUrl = "https://google.co.kr"
        };

        IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(binPath, options);
        driver.Quit();
```

I want to crawl some data from legacy website only work in Internet explorer.
but it code not work at next open IE driver line and just wait then occurs error ' OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:56678/session timed out after 60 seconds.''

To solve this problem, i tried to

- set IEDriverServer.exe (64bit) path on InternetExplorerDriver path
- set to on 'Use security mode' all area option at Internet explorer internet option > security
- Add register subkey `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE`, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE` and add DWORD value `iexplore.exe` with value '0'
- Disabled Enhanced Protected Mode

[image]

Comment: Which version of IE driver are you using for this? Have you tried both 32-bit and 64-bit? Also, you have left out a quotation mark in the InitialBrowserUrl line. I don't know whether it is the same in your original code.